# How would you prove that this sequence converges to $\frac54$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How would you prove that this sequence converges to $\dfrac 54$? $$a_{n}=\dfrac {5n}{4n-3}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Use "$" instead of "<latex>".

Comment: For example you can divide both nominator and denominator by $n$. If you need to prove it using $\epsilon-N$ notations, you should notify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would divide numerator and denominator by $n$, so that

$a_n = \frac{5}{4-\frac{3}{n}}.$

Can you now see what happens as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 5):

1) Intuitive  proof: divide numerator and denominator through $n$ and take the limit. Assume $\frac{1}{n} \to_n 0$.

2) Rigorous: consider $|a_n - \frac{5}{4}| < \varepsilon$. By the definition of convergence, we must find $n_0$ s.t. all $  a_{n \geq n_0}$ are within $\varepsilon-$radius of the limit. Take $n_0 = \frac{15+12 \varepsilon}{16 \varepsilon}$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, the convergence is proven.

Comment: I would say that your first proof is quite rigorous as long as you cite already proven facts (like the fact that the limit of a sum of two convergent sequences is the sum of their limits). I would call the first proof "usual proof" and the second "proof from basic principles".

Comment: Perhaps it's a question of terminology. I call the first proof intuitive because it relies on the fact that intuitively $\frac{1}{n}  \to_n 0$. The second proof only uses the definition and nothing else, hence I call it rigorous.

Comment: Thanks. The second proof looks familiar. We were asked to show it from first principles, so I'm guessing that's what they're after. How did you know what to take n0 as though?

Comment: Yes you're right. That's why I don't like the term 'first principles'  it's too misleading. I'd either say $\varepsilon-\delta$ or 'using the definition of limit'

Answer (score 2):

Given the known answer, you should compute

$$a_n-L=\frac{5n}{4n-3}-\frac54=\frac{12}{4n-3}.$$

What can you conclude ?